# How to let AVPlayer plays mp3 from URL without waiting to load the whole file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I am playing a file using `AVPlayer` and it is working fine. What I am looking for is that when the application plays the file it should play as soon as some enough buffer available. Currently what I have noticed is that if the file is big it waits for longer time to start playing the file which means it waits until the file is loaded in the buffer or so.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your mp3 audio's `URL` should be streaming `url` if you want to play with some buffer, otherwise player will download full mp3 song  data via url and then start play.

Comment: Can you give more details or if there is any article on the same please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, thank you Paul, your hint helped.

I have resolved the issue as follow:

Instead of having the URL as the mp3 file; I have created a text file and called it audio.m3u then I have just wrote the url address of my mp3 file in the newly created file (the m3u). Then played the file (audio.m3u) in the AVPlayer.

thats all :)